# no way to open the image's link

Tags: css

I'm trying to have an image with an opacity color effect on hover and the possibilty to click on it to open the image's link

```css
.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.image img {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.image:after {
    content: '\A';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    opacity: 0;
    background:yellow;
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}

.image:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"><a href="http://wikipedia.org/"><img width="700" height="394" src="http://placehold.it/700x394" class="img-responsive wp-post-image" alt="Responsive image"  sizes="(max-width: 700px) 100vw, 700px"></a></div>
```

but the problem is that they're no way to open the image's link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the absolute positioning; in this case the anchor link doesn't wrap your image, so I have moved your anchor link outside to wrap all the content:

```css
.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.image img {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.image:after {
    content: '\A';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    opacity: 0;
    background:yellow;
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}

.image:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://wikipedia.org/"><div class="image"><img width="700" height="394" src="http://placehold.it/700x394" class="img-responsive wp-post-image" alt="Responsive image"  sizes="(max-width: 700px) 100vw, 700px"></div></a>
```